# OpenXML - Table Creation, How do I create tables without requiring excel to repair them

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I'm creating multiple spreadsheets (separate files), each containing multiple sheets, and when I open the output file of one of these spreadsheets in excel it asks if I want to repair it (this only happens when I add tables), and shows what was repaired:

```
Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)
```

After repairing, the file is in the correct format, but as this is being automated I can't reply on using excel to repair these files. It only causes this problem when I create a table.

For example: I call the Define Table method using the following parameters to create a table of 11 Rows (Rows 2-12 inclusive) and 8 Columns (1-8 inclusive):

```
DefineTable(worksheetPart, 2, 12, 1, 8);
```

The DefineTable method is shown below:

```
private static void DefineTable(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, int rowMin, int rowMax, int colMin, int colMax)
    {
        TableDefinitionPart tableDefinitionPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<TableDefinitionPart>("rId" + (worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.Count() + 1));
        int tableNo = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.Count();

        string reference = ((char)(64 + colMin)).ToString() + rowMin + ":" + ((char)(64 + colMax)).ToString() + rowMax;

        Table table = new Table() { Id = (UInt32)tableNo, Name = "Table" + tableNo, DisplayName = "Table" + tableNo, Reference = reference, TotalsRowShown = false };
        AutoFilter autoFilter = new AutoFilter() { Reference = reference };

        TableColumns tableColumns = new TableColumns() { Count = (UInt32)(colMax - colMin + 1) };
        for (int i = 0; i < (colMax - colMin + 1); i++)
        {
            tableColumns.Append(new TableColumn() { Id = (UInt32)(i + 1), Name = "Column" + i });
        }

        TableStyleInfo tableStyleInfo = new TableStyleInfo() { Name = "TableStyleLight1", ShowFirstColumn = false, ShowLastColumn = false, ShowRowStripes = true, ShowColumnStripes = false };

        table.Append(autoFilter);
        table.Append(tableColumns);
        table.Append(tableStyleInfo);

        tableDefinitionPart.Table = table;

        TableParts tableParts = new TableParts() { Count = (UInt32)1 };
        TablePart tablePart = new TablePart() { Id = "rId" + tableNo };

        tableParts.Append(tablePart);

        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(tableParts);
    }
```

I'm not sure why the table is being constructed incorrectly, I would appreciate any help I can get to fix this.

I will also include table1.xml before and after being repaired:
table1.xml Before Repair:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<x:table id="1" name="Table1" displayName="Table1" ref="A2:H12" 
totalsRowShown="0" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
 <x:autoFilter ref="A2:H12"/>
 <x:tableColumns count="8">
  <x:tableColumn id="1" name="Column0"/>
  <x:tableColumn id="2" name="Column1"/>
  <x:tableColumn id="3" name="Column2"/>
  <x:tableColumn id="4" name="Column3"/>
  <x:tableColumn id="5" name="Column4"/>
  <x:tableColumn id="6" name="Column5"/>
  <x:tableColumn id="7" name="Column6"/>
  <x:tableColumn id="8" name="Column7"/>
 </x:tableColumns>
 <x:tableStyleInfo name="TableStyleLight1" showFirstColumn="0" 
showLastColumn="0" showRowStripes="1" showColumnStripes="0"/>
</x:table>
```

table1.xml After Repair:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<table xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" 
xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" 
mc:Ignorable="xr xr3" xr:uid="{00000000-000C-0000-FFFF-FFFF00000000}" id="1" 
name="Table1" displayName="Table1" ref="A2:H12" totalsRowShown="0">
 <autoFilter xr:uid="{00000000-0009-0000-0100-000001000000}" ref="A2:H12"/>
 <tableColumns count="8">
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000001000000}" id="1" 
name="Column0"/>
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000002000000}" id="2" 
name="Column1"/>
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000003000000}" id="3" 
name="Column2"/>
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000004000000}" id="4" 
name="Column3"/>
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000005000000}" id="5" 
name="Column4"/>
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000006000000}" id="6" 
name="Column5"/>
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000007000000}" id="7" 
name="Column6"/>
  <tableColumn xr3:uid="{00000000-0010-0000-0000-000008000000}" id="8" 
name="Column7"/>
 </tableColumns>
 <tableStyleInfo name="TableStyleLight1" showFirstColumn="0" 
showLastColumn="0" showRowStripes="1" showColumnStripes="0"/>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using your debugger to step through the code?

Comment: Yes, I tried using my debugger, and didn't find the issue. I tried adding 3 tables to 2 different sheets in one spreadsheet, and I noticed that the repaired records were for tables 1 to 6. This makes me think I might need to change TableIds from 1-3 on sheet 1 and 1-3 on sheet 2, to 1-3 on sheet 1 and 4-6 on sheet 2.

Comment: I recommend you use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to track down the problem in your code. Create a minimal workbook that has the problem. Open the workbook, let Excel repair it, then save as to a different name. Open the repaired workbook and look at the code the Tool proposes to create it. Compare that with your current code. It might also help to open the "bad" workbook in the Tool then use the "Compare" functionality to compare it to the "good" version.

Comment: I did not know this was a tool, and holy wow this is a great tool.
Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever resolve this issue? I have the exact same issue now. Excel complains there's an issue with the file. When it loads, it looks fine. And when I compare the markup to Excels fixed markup, I see what you do. And I don't see any property to set to have that `xr3:uid` element to show up.

Answer (score 6):

I fought with this same issue for several days.  I was dynamically creating an Excel spreadsheet using Open XML.  It all worked fine until I tried adding a table.  Once I did that I kept getting the warning when opening the spreadsheet about it needing repair.

I finally fixed the problem by adding the column heading text to the spreadsheet data.  For example if I had a table on cells A1:C7 with 2 columns defined (names of "Column1" and "Column2"), along with adding the table and columns, I also added the text "Column1" to cell A1 and "Column2" to cell B1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add cell values for the specified column values as well as defining `TableParts` only once.

Further, for repetitive usage with an offset column, the column id has to be added to the `colMin` variable.

With these changes it should work.

```
public static Table DefineTable(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, int rowMin, int rowMax, int colMin, int colMax)
    {
        TableDefinitionPart tableDefinitionPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<TableDefinitionPart>("rId" + (worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.Count() + 1));
        int tableNo = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.Count();

        string reference = ((char)(64 + colMin)).ToString() + rowMin + ":" + ((char)(64 + colMax)).ToString() + rowMax;

        Table table = new Table() { Id = (UInt32)tableNo, Name = "Table" + tableNo, DisplayName = "Table" + tableNo, Reference = reference, TotalsRowShown = false };
        AutoFilter autoFilter = new AutoFilter() { Reference = reference };

        TableColumns tableColumns = new TableColumns() { Count = (UInt32)(colMax - colMin + 1) };
        for (int i = 0; i < (colMax - colMin + 1); i++)
        {
            tableColumns.Append(new TableColumn() { Id = (UInt32)(colMin + i), Name = "Column" + i }); //changed i+1 -> colMin + i
            //Add cell values (shared string)
        }

        TableStyleInfo tableStyleInfo = new TableStyleInfo() { Name = "TableStyleLight1", ShowFirstColumn = false, ShowLastColumn = false, ShowRowStripes = true, ShowColumnStripes = false };

        table.Append(autoFilter);
        table.Append(tableColumns);
        table.Append(tableStyleInfo);

        tableDefinitionPart.Table = table;
        
        TableParts tableParts = (TableParts)worksheetPart.Worksheet.ChildElements.Where(ce => ce is TableParts).FirstOrDefault(); // Add table parts only once
        if (tableParts is null )
        {
            tableParts = new TableParts();
            tableParts.Count = (UInt32)0;
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(tableParts);
        }

        tableParts.Count += (UInt32)1;
        TablePart tablePart = new TablePart() { Id = "rId" + tableNo };

        tableParts.Append(tablePart);

        return table;
    }
```