# Populate table with OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I want to create an Excel template file, and then open it and populate it with data from code using OpenXml.

Is it possible to create the table in Excel, and then populate that table by name from code?

I want to be able to refer to the table by name. Ideally, this will allow me to insert rows and the table would get taller to accommodate those rows. And any table header or footer would remain intact.

I'm new to working with OpenXML. If this is possible, can someone point me to some documentation on how to do it?

Comment: Does this help: [OpenXML - Table Creation, How do I create tables without requiring excel to repair them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440352/openxml-table-creation-how-do-i-create-tables-without-requiring-excel-to-repa)

Comment: @MaciejLos: No, I want to create tables in an Excel template file and then insert data into the table from code.

Comment: As to me, it would be much easier to insert data into Excel file via OleDb. Did you think about this?

Comment: @MaciejLos: No, that requires Excel on the machine. Not at all appropriate for what I'm doing.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. Excel is not required. You need only ACE.OLEDB driver installed on the system. See: [ACE.OLEDB](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/), That means - you need to download and install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with OpenXml. Basically, if the table already exists you just need to write the required data, find the table and then update the `Reference` property of the table to reflect the cells the table now covers.

A [`Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.table) exists inside a [`TableDefinitionPart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.tabledefinitionpart) which can be found from the [`Worksheetpart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.worksheetpart). That sounds complicated but finding the correct table isn't too bad.

Assuming you have a table in column A with no data other than the header and named *MyTable* in an existing Excel file like this

[image: Before]

The following will add some data to the table:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "Sheet1").First();
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;
    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

    //write some new data
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        //rowIndex takes into account the header (i.e. we're filling A2-A11)
        uint rowIndex = (uint)i + 1;
        Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
        Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = $"A{rowIndex}", CellValue = new CellValue(i), DataType = CellValues.Number };
        row.Append(cell);

        sheetData.Append(row);
    }
    //find the table
    Table table = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Table.Name == "MyTable")?.Table;
    //update the reference of the table (11 is 10 data rows and 1 header)
    table.Reference = "A1:A11";
}
```

Giving a result like this:

[image: After]