# Adding Table to openxml spreadsheet causes excel to repair workbook when opening

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm working on a small excel export. All the data is there but adding a spreadsheet table for the range in question to provide quick and easy access to sort&filter when the user opens the file in excel causes a problem. The problem is that when the file is opened in excel `we found a problem with some content in...` and a query if they `should try to recover as much as we can`.

After repairing it excel states that it `was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content`. with `Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)` listed in a text field below. After this the workbook behaves as I intended, with a table.

I have searched and tried almost everything I've stumbled upon. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440352/openxml-table-creation-how-do-i-create-tables-without-requiring-excel-to-repa) is very similar but the proposed answer does not work for me.

A minimal example with the problem is [here](https://github.com/CalculationCycle/openxml-spreadsheet-with-table). It generates two excel files, one with the table added and one without. The one without is previewable in Explorer, the problematic one  displays the message:

> *The file can't be previewed because of an error in the Microsoft Excel previewer.*

Nuget used: DocumentFormat.OpenXml version 2.14.0. Excel version is office365, desktop version. Running under Windows 10.

What I have tried:

- Various openxml validation tools, no errors found
- Saved the (by excel) repaired file and compared the content of those two. I don't find any difference that in my head can serve as an explanation

It would be very nice to have the table already in place when the excel file is generated.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using ExcelGenerator;

namespace ConsoleAppOpenXmlSpreadsheetWithTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var headerRow = new List<string> { "Company", "Country", "Fruit" };
            var exportRowList = new List<ExcelExportRow>();
            exportRowList.Add(new ExcelExportRow() { Company ="Spanish Oranges A", Country = "Spain", Fruit ="Oranges"});
            exportRowList.Add(new ExcelExportRow() { Company = "Mexican Oranges Ltd", Country = "Mexico", Fruit = "Oranges" });
            exportRowList.Add(new ExcelExportRow() { Company = "Medit. Bananas", Country = "Spain", Fruit = "Bananas" });
            exportRowList.Add(new ExcelExportRow() { Company = "Mexican Bananas", Country = "Mexico", Fruit = "Bananas" });
            exportRowList.Add(new ExcelExportRow() { Company = "Mexican Sweet Oranges", Country = "Mexico", Fruit = "Oranges" });
            using (var memoryStream = ExcelFileGenerator.GenerateArticleListWithImagesExcelFile(headerRow, exportRowList, false))
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream("OpenXmlSpreadsheet.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
            using (var memoryStream = ExcelFileGenerator.GenerateArticleListWithImagesExcelFile(headerRow, exportRowList, true))
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream("OpenXmlSpreadsheetWithTable.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ExcelFileGenerator.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace ExcelGenerator
{
    public class ExcelExportRow
    {
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Fruit { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ExcelFileGenerator
    {
        private const int normalFontStyleIndex = 0;
        private const int boldFontStyleIndex = 1;

        public static MemoryStream GenerateArticleListWithImagesExcelFile(List<string> headerRow, List<ExcelExportRow> excelExportRoListw, bool insertTable)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
                workbookPart.Workbook = workbook;

                WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rIdStyles");

                Stylesheet stylesheet = StyleSheet();
                workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;
                workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();

                Sheets sheets = new Sheets();

                //get the string name of the columns
                string[] excelColumnNamesTitle = new string[5];
                for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
                    excelColumnNamesTitle[n] = GetExcelColumnName(n);

                var columns = new Columns();
                columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 1, Max = 1, CustomWidth = true, Width = 24 });
                columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 2, Max = 3, CustomWidth = true, Width = 12 });
                worksheet.Append(columns);

                if (excelExportRoListw is not null)
                {
                    Row rowTitle = new Row() { RowIndex = (UInt32Value)1 };
                    for (int c = 0; c < headerRow.Count; c++)
                    {
                        AppendTextCell(excelColumnNamesTitle[c], headerRow[c], rowTitle, boldFontStyleIndex);
                    }
                    sheetData.Append(rowTitle);

                    uint rowNumber = 2;
                    foreach (var excelExportRow in excelExportRoListw)
                    {
                        var spreadsheetRow = new Row() { RowIndex = (UInt32Value)rowNumber };
                        AppendTextCell(excelColumnNamesTitle[0], excelExportRow.Company, spreadsheetRow, normalFontStyleIndex);
                        AppendTextCell(excelColumnNamesTitle[2], excelExportRow.Country, spreadsheetRow, normalFontStyleIndex);
                        AppendTextCell(excelColumnNamesTitle[3], excelExportRow.Fruit, spreadsheetRow, normalFontStyleIndex);
                        sheetData.Append(spreadsheetRow);
                        rowNumber++;
                    }

                    worksheet.Append(sheetData);
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;
                }

                // Table
                if (insertTable)
                    DefineTable(worksheetPart, 1, 1 + excelExportRoListw.Count, 0, 2);

                // Wrap up and save
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Name = "Export", SheetId = (UInt32Value)1, Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart) };
                sheets.Append(sheet);
                workbook.Append(sheets);
                workbook.Save();
                document.Close();
            }

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return memoryStream;
        }


        private static void DefineTable(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, int rowMin, int rowMax, int colMin, int colMax)
        {
            #region Table
            string rangeReference = $"{GetExcelColumnName(colMin)}{rowMin}:{GetExcelColumnName(colMax)}{rowMax}";
            int tableNo = 1;

            Table table = new Table()
            {
                Id = (UInt32)tableNo,
                Name = "Table" + tableNo,
                DisplayName = "Table" + tableNo,
                Reference = rangeReference,
                TotalsRowShown = false
            };

            AutoFilter autoFilter = new AutoFilter() { Reference = rangeReference };

            TableColumns tableColumns = new TableColumns() { Count = (UInt32)(colMax - colMin + 1) };
            for (int i = 0; i < (colMax - colMin + 1); i++)
            {
                tableColumns.Append(new TableColumn() { Id = (UInt32)(i + 1), Name = "Column" + i });
            }

            TableStyleInfo tableStyleInfo = new TableStyleInfo()
            {
                Name = "TableStyleMedium1",
                ShowFirstColumn = false,
                ShowLastColumn = false,
                ShowRowStripes = true,
                ShowColumnStripes = false
            };

            table.Append(autoFilter);
            table.Append(tableColumns);
            table.Append(tableStyleInfo);
            #endregion

            string tableRefId = "rIdTable1";

            // Add table to worksheet - two different things implictly linked by using the same refId
            TableDefinitionPart tableDefinitionPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<TableDefinitionPart>(tableRefId);
            tableDefinitionPart.Table = table;
            
            TableParts tableParts = new TableParts();
            TablePart tablePart = new TablePart() { Id = tableRefId };
            tableParts.Append(tablePart);
            tableParts.Count = 1;
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(tableParts);
        }

        #region Excel Helper funcs
        private static void AppendTextCell(string cellReference, string cellStringValue, Row excelRow, UInt32Value styleIndex)
        {
            //  Add a new Excel Cell to our Row
            Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference, DataType = CellValues.String };
            CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
            cellValue.Text = cellStringValue;
            cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex;
            cell.Append(cellValue);
            excelRow.Append(cell);
        }

        private static string GetExcelColumnName(int columnIndex)
        {
            if (columnIndex < 26)
                return ((char)('A' + columnIndex)).ToString();

            char firstChar = (char)('A' + (columnIndex / 26) - 1);
            char secondChar = (char)('A' + (columnIndex % 26));

            return string.Format("{0}{1}", firstChar, secondChar);
        }
        #endregion Helper funcs

        #region Stylesheet
        private static Stylesheet StyleSheet()
        {
            Stylesheet styleSheet = new Stylesheet();

            Fonts fonts = new Fonts();
            // 0 - normal fonts
            Font myFont = new Font()
            {
                FontSize = new FontSize() { Val = 11 },
                Color = new Color() { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("FF000000") },
                FontName = new FontName() { Val = "Arial" }
            };
            fonts.Append(myFont);

            //1 - font bold
            myFont = new Font()
            {
                Bold = new Bold(),
                FontSize = new FontSize() { Val = 11 },
                Color = new Color() { Rgb = HexBinaryValue.FromString("FF000000") },
                FontName = new FontName() { Val = "Arial" }
            };
            fonts.Append(myFont);


            Fills fills = new Fills();
            //default fill
            Fill fill = new Fill()
            {
                PatternFill = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None }
            };
            fills.Append(fill);

            Borders borders = new Borders();
            //normal borders
            Border border = new Border()
            {
                LeftBorder = new LeftBorder(),
                RightBorder = new RightBorder(),
                TopBorder = new TopBorder(),
                BottomBorder = new BottomBorder(),
                DiagonalBorder = new DiagonalBorder()
            };
            borders.Append(border);

            CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats();
            //0- normalFontStyleIndex for normal cells
            CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat()
            {
                FontId = 0,
                FillId = 0,
                BorderId = 0,
                ApplyFill = false
            };
            cellFormats.Append(cellFormat);

            //1 - boldFontStyleIndex for header row
            cellFormat = new CellFormat()
            {
                FontId = 1,
                FillId = 0,
                BorderId = 0,
                ApplyFill = false
            };
            cellFormats.Append(cellFormat);

            styleSheet.Append(fonts);
            styleSheet.Append(fills);
            styleSheet.Append(borders);
            styleSheet.Append(cellFormats);

            TableStyles tableStyles = new TableStyles()
            {
                Count = 0,
                DefaultTableStyle = "TableStyleMedium1",
                DefaultPivotStyle = "PivotStyleLight16"
            };
            styleSheet.Append(tableStyles);

            return styleSheet;
        }
        #endregion Stylesheet
    }
}
```

Comment: Code added to question and MIT license added to github repo.